# Magento logouts after saving product image

Tags: product, catalog, image, patches, ce-1.9.1.1

I'm using magento 1.9.1.1 And strange thing happened after installing security patches.
When I try to edit product image, upload works normally. But when I click save product, Magento automatically logouts from admin panel and image won't save. This only happens when I try to change or set product image. Any other information changes without any issues.

Enabled and checked the logs. NGINX, system, exception etc.. Nothing strange shows up.

Anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue. Turns out i had to increase session life time in admin System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie management. And that fixed the issue..

Comment: congo congo :) :)